# How to use VST plugin dll in C#?

Tags: audio, vst

I am completely newbie to VST development. I want to achieve http://www.cloneensemble.com/ like functionality in C#. This is a VST plugin.

There are two ways to do that.

1. By using their DLL in my project and somehow giving input to dll by calling  some of its function and applying the effect on the input.
2. By developing it from scratch in c#.

I don't know how to do any of the above cases please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com) to host the unmanaged plugin.

VST.NET allows you to build managed VST plugins that can be hosted in unmanaged hosts (Cubase, Live, Reaper etc) but it also allows you to write a managed VST host that allows managed and unmanaged plugins to be loaded. Sounds like you only want to load one plugin. Do realize that it might not be as easy as you think though.

EDIT: Check out the Host sample at: http://vstnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Samples/Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Host/MainForm.cs

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I have installed VST.Net Template there are only two types there, both are pulgins i dont see any way to load VST Plugin there. Can you please elaborate a little more. Secondly documentation part on codeplex link is not very helpful.

Comment: Added a link to the host sample. Note that this sample only demonstrates the principles of talking to plugins, it is not a fully functional host application.